# Is the language L ={a^n b^k c^m | k>=0, n>m} regular?

Tags: pumping-lemma

I have to explain using the pummping-lemma that the language:

`L ={a^n b^k c^m | k>=0, n>m}`

is not regular.

Can someone please explain how it is done on this particular language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I made 2 mistakes here, first the pumping must be related to the word you use ( or at least it seems so after watching a lot of examples ), Secondly, its the other way around if you find any good match, then you cant use it as a wrong example. Provided my answer was wrong i ll edit with how it can really be proved.

The pummping lemma is about proving that is not a regular language by using contradiction, you first have to assume a string you provide that must be valid for L is regular, then you have to divide this string into 3 parts following some rules:

1. |y| > 0
2. |xy| <= P (P represents the minimun length of the word)
3. xy^nz with n>=0 is included in the language (L)

So lets take for example P is 1:

> For using this one i ll not use any b's provided the language allows it.
> What this means is i ll have my language expressed this way L = { a^P+1 c^P } which is included in L and is valid so lets say aac (this one is in L)

- only way to divide this is (x:a,y:a,z:c)

With this in mind you can prove is not regular using 2 of the 3 statements

> |xy| is greater than P because P is 1 and xy is 2
>
> xy^nz if we use n = 0, then the result would be ac which is not included in the language.

Comment: So I have to contradict any word in the language that it is not possible to pump it up ?

Comment: I ll edit my answer is wrong, while i was researching i found something badly explain. i ll add another comment when its solved

Comment: Now it is solved. And to answer provided a P you have to find all of the possibilities to be contradictory if not, you cannot use it. https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/fa01/cse105_B/lec6seq.pdf in that pdf is better explained. And im sorry for the misinformation i gave you the first time